# ListView update refresh in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-fragmentactivity

I have a **fragment class that contains a ListView** and I have my own custom layout for the list, The process of adding something on the list is, within the fragment there is an add button, this button when clicked will open DialogFragment then passes data into SQL, everything works fine but the ListView does not refresh when something is added. I have been using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

How can I refresh the ListView?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

    add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    db = new dbhelp(getActivity());
    db.open();
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mydialog dialog = new mydialog();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog Fragment");

        }
    });

    populateList(view);
    return view;
}
    private void generateList(View view){

    Cursor cursor = control.getdata();

    CustomAdp adapter = new CustomAdp(getActivity(), cursor);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: there is no observer for sqlite database by defualt ... you need to do by yourself ... the easiest(for me) way is to use ContentProvider and Loaders API ...

Comment: @Selvin would you mind providing an example? how would I implement that, I use a Cursor to obtain the data.

Comment: there is a plenty examples over the internet ....

Comment: where you use `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: @Xcihnegn I put it onCreateView and onActivityCreated but it wont work

Comment: That should be called after `add` button and actually add items to `ArrayList` of adapter

Comment: @Xcihnegn I tried putting it after PositiveButton is clicked on my DialogFragment but it makes onClick nullpointer

Comment: You should call it after adding items to `ArrayList` actually finished

Comment: @Xcihnegn I am new to this, can you write an example, do I create a new method to put cursor in arrayList

Comment: Can you post the full code?